# GTK# TreeView First row colored

Tags: c#, mono, gtk#

Iam can't get my head around this problem. I got TreeView control and I want to color first row. Could anyone tell me how to do that ?! Playing around with cellrenderer colors whole column and can't force it to color single row.

I would appreceiate any help

Answer (score 2):

If what you are looking for is to have alternating row colors, you can affect this by setting RulesHint=true for the treeview.

If instead you are just looking to affect the background color of a single row, you will probably have to use the cell renderers and bind some attributes.  For example, CellRendererText has a few different ways to set the background color, and you can bind any of those properties to a column in your model/store to control the color behind the text in that cell.

You don't just set the color on the CellRenderer, you bind it to a model column so that you can set the color in that column for each row individually.